# The feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces' is not recognized by XML::SAX::ExpatXS

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to submit a Perl validation script to the LSF server. The script runs fine on my local machine but the same script is throwing error

> The feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces' is not recognized by XML::SAX::ExpatXS

on the LSF machine.

The LSF machines do not have access to internet.

Google doen't result in any good answers, please help how can I identify the config difference between the two machines which is causing this issue.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code producing this error? Just like that it's pretty hard - at least to me - to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The (original Java) SAX API lets the client set options on the parser using property names which always take the form of URIs, of which http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces is an example. These are simply unique names, they are not locations on the internet that will be accessed. The SAX API specification says that every conformant parser must recognize certain options, of which http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces is an example. The error message means that you are using a parser which does not conform to this specification.

Beyond that, I'm afraid I don't know enough about your processing environment to know what you can do about it. In the Java world, a workaround might be to insert a dummy parser as a man-in-the-middle to intercept the request from the client and avoid passing it on to the real parser.